# ESP32 WIFI error when trying to initialize WIFI after stopping and deinit WIFI driver

Tags: esp32, wifi, error

I have a firebeetle ESP32 board and I use VScode with platformIO. My platform is *espressif32* v5.0.0 and the framework is *arduino*.

I am currently implementing a WIFI connection as follows:

```
bool init_wifi_STA()
{
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I do not need WIFI anymore, I am calling the following sequence:

```
esp_wifi_disconnect();
esp_wifi_stop();
esp_wifi_deinit();
```

When I want to connect to wifi again using my `init_wifi_STA()` function I get the following error:

> [489781][E][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1053] mode(): Could not set mode! 12289
> [489781][E][WiFiSTA.cpp:227] begin(): STA enable failed!

I already found this [github issue](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/4842), but checking my library, it looks like the bug was removed (code section from `WiFiGeneric.cpp` - mentioned by the github issue):

```
static bool wifiLowLevelDeinit(){
    if(lowLevelInitDone){
        lowLevelInitDone = !(esp_wifi_deinit() == ESP_OK);
    }
    return !lowLevelInitDone;
}
```

However, I am still getting this error. Any idea where it comes from and how to avoid it?